# Should I use URL rewriting to protect against XSS

Tags: java, tomcat, xss

Let's say someone enters the following URL in their browser:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/<script>alert(1)</script>
```

The page is displayed as normal with the alert popup as well. I think this should result in a 404, but how do I best achieve that?

My webapp is running on a Tomcat 7 server. Modern browser will automatically protect against this, but older ones, I am looking at you IE6, wont.

Comment: What happens when ie6 sends this request to your tomcat 7 server?  Injected 404 page?

Comment: @xelco52 - No, it shows an alert with the message '1' and carries on as normal. I want it to go to a 404 page. At least that's what I think it should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

Created a high level servlet filter which uses OWASP's HTML sanitizer to check for dodgy characters. If there are any, I redirect to our 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are actually getting a 404 page, but that page includes the resource (in this case a piece of JavaScript code) and doesn't do any converting of < and > to their respective HTML entities. I've seen this happen on several websites.

The solution would be to create a custom 404 page which doesn't echo back the resource to the page, or that does proper HTML entity conversion beforehand. There are plenty of tutorials you can find through Google which should help you do this.

Comment: No that's not what's happening at all

Comment: Can you give any other details? Where in the source code is the JavaScript code being returned to the user?

Answer (score -1):

You should put a filter in your webapp to protect against an XSS attack.

Get all the parameters from the HttpServletRequest object and replace any parameter with value starting with  with spaces in filter code.

This way any harmful JS script won't reach your server side components.

Comment: The URL itself is not a parameter though is it?